# How can i add links to all of my options in a dropdown list in Yii framework without model?

Tags: php, yii

I 'm using the code below to generate a dropdown list in Yii framework without model. How can i link every item to a different url?

```
<?php echo CHtml::dropDownList('category','',array(
''=>'Please Select...',
'Phones'=>'Phones',
'Laptops'=>'Laptops',
'Desktops'=>'Desktops',
))  
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want the html result

```
    <select id="device_name" name="device[name]">
        <option value="">Please Select...</option>
        <option value="Phones">Phones</option>
        <option value="Laptops">Laptops</option>
        <option value="Desktops">Desktops</option>            
    </select>
```

you could use this code

```
<?php 

    echo CHtml::dropDownList('device[name]',
            2, // the selected values
            array('Phones'=>'Phones',
                  'Laptops'=>'Laptops',
                  'Desktops'=>'Desktops' ),
            array('empty'=>'Please Select...')
        );
```

you can find more sample  here http://www.bsourcecode.com/2013/02/chtml-dropdownlist-in-yii/